# Need a single SELECT query in php

Tags: mysql

I am having three parameters $page, $date, $search. i need a single select sql query where i have to check all the three variables one by one whether any of these variables is having some value or not or if all of the three variables is having some value. According to which it will match from the database and give the result. Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.  We are not a free coding or homework service.  Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i need this in php. I am generating an excel file. i get three parameters in the pdf page $search,$page and $ date. I have to make a SINGLE select query .

Comment: @Sajan update the code you tried

Comment: in main page,     window.location = 'print.php?search='+search+'&page_value='+page_value+'&date_value='+date_value; . And in excel.php  <?php
  require ('dbconfig.php');

 echo $date_value=$_GET['date_value'];
 echo $page_value=$_GET['page_value'];
 echo $search=$_GET['search'];
?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make where clause as follows in your Select query.(Below is MS SQL format, you can modify CASE statement equivalent with MY SQL)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (if more than one table, you can use join)
WHERE  TABLE.search_COLUMN = case when @search <> '' then  @search else TABLE.search_COLUMN end
AND
TABLE.page_value_COLUMN = case when @page_value <> '' then  @page_value else TABLE.page_value_COLUMN end
AND
TABLE.date_‌​value_COLUMN = case when @date_‌​value <> '' then  @date_‌​value else TABLE.date_‌​value_COLUMN end
```

Comment: Sajan, plz also mark this answer useful. Thanks & best of luck!